# Add vertical space for individual lines in an array in LyX

Tags: lyx, arrays

I know that I can add vertical space for individual lines in an array in LaTeX by including an optional argument after the line break (see example below). Is there way to do this in LyX without using a text editor to directly modify the LyX source file?

```
\[
\left[\begin{array}{cc}
\dfrac{1}{s} & \dfrac{1}{s}\\[1em]
\dfrac{1}{s} & \dfrac{1}{s}
\end{array}\right]
\]
```